# Cant understand why this code output in a result:ERROR

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, x87

I think I'm using the right commands to do this task, but for some reason the result is wrong.

I have already tried to change this string `_res1 db 14 DUP(0),10,13`. I also tried to change `dword on REAL4`, but its was pointless

```
.486 ;sets the CPU to 80486 instruction set mode

.model flat, stdcall ;sets the memory model to flat and the calling convention to stdcall

option casemap :none ;sets the case sensitivity option for symbols to none     
include \masm32\include\windows.inc ; connecting the windows.inc program file    
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm ; MASM support macros
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc ; connecting the program file masm.inc
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc ; connecting the program file gdi32.inc
include \masm32\include\fpu.inc ; connecting the program file fpu.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc ; connecting the user32.inc program file
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc ; connecting the program file kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc ; connecting the msvcrt.inc program file 
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib ; connecting the msvcrt.lib library
includelib \masm32\lib\fpu.lib ; connecting the fpu.lib library
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib ; connecting the masm32.lib library
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib ; connecting the gdi32.lib library
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib ; connecting the user32.lib library
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib ; connecting the kernel32.lib library

uselib masm32, comctl32, ws2_32 

.data ; data definition directive
_const_A DWORD 1.5 ;declaration of the constant
_const_B DWORD 0.7 ;declaration of the constant
_result DWORD 0.0 ;declaration the result
_title db "Laboratorna robota 5",0 ; set the title for the message box
strbuf dw ?,0 ; define a buffer for the message box output
_text db " Student of KNEU IITE",10,
    "Output result by MessageBox:",10, 
    "A+B",10,
    "Result: " ; set the message box output text

_res1 db 14 DUP(0),10,13 ; Define a string with a length of 14 characters filled with 0s, and line feed and carriage return at the end
    
.code ; Command segment start directive
start: ; Program start mark with the name _start
    finit ;initialization of coprocessor
    fld _const_A ;
    fadd _const_B ;  
    fstp _result ; save value in variable _result
    invoke FpuFLtoA, 0, 10, ADDR _res1, SRC1_FPU or SRC2_DIMM
    invoke MessageBox, 0, offset _text, offset _title, MB_ICONINFORMATION
    invoke ExitProcess, 0 ; exit the program
end start ; End of the program
```

Screenshot of program:
[image]

OllyDBg screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `fld _const_A` puts _const_A in ST(0). `fadd _const_B` will take _const_B and add it to ST(0) and put the result in ST(0). That means ST(0) should be both constants added together. The problem I think is that `fstp _result` stores ST(0) to `_result` but it also POPS the value in ST(0) so there is nothing on the FPU stack.. I assume `FpuFLtoA`'s flag of SRC1_FPU means convert the float on the top of the stack ST(0) to ASCII but there is nothing on the FPU stack and that likely results in the error. What happens if you use `fst _result` to keep the value on the FPU stack after storing to _result

Comment: Alternatively I think you could use `ftsp _result` but rather than convert the value on the FPU stack to ASCII you could convert the value at `_result`. I think to do that you can pass `offset _result1` as the first parameter and replace SRC1_FPU to SRC1_DMEM to `FpuFLtoA`